# Creating SQL CE4 databases

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I've downloaded the RTM version of SQL CE (Compact Edition) and installed it. I've installed the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). I understand that SQL CE4 support within Visual Studio won't happen until SP1 drops.

The problem is, while I have tools to edit the CE Database, I can't find a way to actually *create* a SQL CE4 database. I figure I must be missing something obvious, but 20 minutes of searching hasn't turned up anything. How do I create a SQL CE4 database?

Thanks,
Erick

Edit: I would rather avoid installing and running WebMatrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server Compact Toolbox also allows you to create a database file (via the Add Connection dialog)

Comment: This is definitely one of those doh moments. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better solution, but you could try out [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). With it I created an Orchard site, but after creating the site you can create new databases by clicking the 'New Database' button.
Really easy. Don't think this is the best option though...

Comment: I might end up doing this, but I would really rather not. As you mention, it is not the best option. Thanks - Erick